# Dynamically set the map tiles based on the current location using mappa.js and p5.js

Tags: leaflet, p5.js

I'm trying to dynamically set the map tiles based on the current location using mappa.js and p5.js. Now, I'm able to set the map to location [0,0] using mappa.js and then get location from navigator and draw an eclipse using p5.js. But the map stays centered at [0,0]. I want the map's center to be the current location. I couldn't find much docs to help me.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/mapkbalaji/pen/eYBRbWo)

```
<html>
<head>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.16/p5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/mappa-mundi@0.0.5/dist/mappa.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
var mappa
var canvas
var myMap
var init = true
var options= {
            lat: 0,
            lng: 0,
            zoom: 4,
            style: "http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
        },
mappa = new Mappa("Leaflet");

function setup() {
  if(init) {
  canvas = createCanvas(600, 600);
    init = false
  }
  myMap = mappa.tileMap(options);
  myMap.overlay(canvas)
  myMap.onChange(drawCurrentLocation)
}


function draw() {
 
  drawCurrentLocation()
  
}

function drawCurrentLocation() {

                console.log("Current location");
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                        options.lat = position.coords.latitude
                        options.lng = position.coords.longitude
                    })


            clear()

            const myLocation = myMap.latLngToPixel(options.lat, options.lng);
            let c = color(0, 0, 255);
fill(c);
noStroke();

ellipse(myLocation.x, myLocation.y, 10, 10);

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```